# Can I restore the input field values after validation through custom request objects in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

Let's say I have a simple contact form.

```
<form action="/message" method="post">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Your Message: </label>
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit Message</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my controller to handle that request:

```
public function sendMessage(ContactRequest $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Notice that I am injecting `ContactRequest` object, so the validation is working perfectly.

## The Problem

How can I restore the old input values in the contact form? So that the user wouldn't have to refill all of the fields.

Comment: is it after validation is correct or after it fails

Comment: You get the point :) @GideonAppoh!

Comment: still not anwering my question, is it when validation has passed or when it has failed

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If the ContactRequest validation fails you will be redirected to your form with the errors and also the old input.

So just use **{{ old('field') }}** in your blade file.

Example for your code:

```
<form action="/message" method="post">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email: </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}"  class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Your Message: </label>
    <textarea name="message" class="form-control">{{ old('message') }}"</textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit Message</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use "old input" method:

```
$request->flash(); //to put the posted data to session
```

and

```
$username = $request->old('username'); //to get the values you previously stored
```

If you're doing a redirect 8back to your form) then you can flash it this way:

```
return redirect('form')->withInput();
```

It is even easier to get the old values in your blade template this way:

```
{{ old('username') }}
```

More about the "old input" way can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#old-input)